# My Visual Studio 2010 is unable to open msoftcon.h header file. What do I do now?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to draw circles.  My Visual Studio 2010 is unable to open msoftcon.h header file.  What I do now?

Comment: I believe msoftcon.h has been deprecated for a while now. If you want to do console graphics you might want to look at pdcurses

Answer (score 1):

There is no msoftcon.h header file included with Visual Studio.  You will have to find this somewhere else, as it's not part of the normal distribution.

Comment: Isn't is part of C++? Or has it been replaced by a more modern equivalent? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229031/msoftcon-h-in-xcode

Comment: No, they are Microsoft console specific.  I don't know if they were once included or not, but they haven't been in years.  Not even sure if they work in non-DOS consoles (the command prompt you have in XP or Windows 7 is not DOS, it's a Win32 Console)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking [here](http://discuss.pcmag.com/forums/thread/419651002.aspx) for it... seems to be an old header file.